# Can I get dplyr output as value, and not as data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

There is a particular reoccurring problem that is very frustrating and I can't figure out the correct way to do this in dplyr.

How do you get dplyr to save a 'result' as a numeric value, and not a tibble data frame?

**Code:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
flights <- flights


a <- flights %>% filter(carrier == "AA") %>% length()

b <- flights %>% filter(carrier == "AA") %>% mean()

c <- flights %>% filter(carrier == "AA") %>% summarise(mean(hour))
```

**These three lines represents the source of my frustration.**

a. Why does 'a' work, i.e it returns a Value? (Bonus question, why is there the letter L next to 19 in the global environment?)

b. Why does this not work? It seems like it "should" if you compare it to the line above.

c. This *kinda* works in that I get the mean - but how do I get it as just a value (I want to use the value in other calculations, so I don't want a dataframe).

Obviously there is some nuance to dplyr that Iv'e not understood so far.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

SOLUTION:

```
mean <- flights %>% filter(carrier == "AA") %>% pull(hour) %>% mean()
```

pull() extracts a single column

L means intager

thanks all!

Comment: L means integer.

Comment: There's some info here on getting vector output out of dplyr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149306/dplyrselect-one-column-and-output-as-vector

Comment: don't use `c` as a variable, maybe try `A`, `B`, `C` as examples (`c()` is a built-in function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a.** `length()` returns the number of elements in an object. When the object is a  data.frame (or tibble) it will return the number of columns. The `L` after the number means it is an integer.

**b.** `mean()` requieres a numeric vector to work. In **b** you are passing a tibble to the function.

**c.** `dplyr` functions are meant to receive tibbles for input and produce tibbles for output. You can `pull()` a column of your tibble so it becomes a vector.

```r
C <- flights %>% filter(carrier == "AA") %>% pull(hour) %>% mean()
```